# UIImage placeholder flashing before cache is loaded

Tags: swift, caching, swiftui

I am attempting to display an image that was recently cached. The issue I am having is the placeholder is briefly flashing on the screen every time I enter the view. Not sure what could be causing this behavior.

I believe I am caching this correctly, and again the URL does load correctly. The issue would be the placeholder flashing on the screen for about a half a second before displaying the cached image. (Unless I"m completely not caching it after all and the URL is still displaying, not the cached image)

```
class UrlImageModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    var urlString: String?
    var imageCache = CacheImageManager.getImageCache()
    
    init (urlString: String?) {
        self.urlString = urlString
        loadImage()
    }
    
    func loadImage(){
        if loadImageFromCache(){
            print("cache located")
            return
        }
        print("cache not detected ")
         loadImageFromURL()
    }
    
    func loadImageFromCache() -> Bool {
        guard let urlString = urlString else {
            return false
        }
        
        guard let cacheImage = imageCache.getCache(forKey: urlString) else {
            return false
        }
        image = cacheImage
        return true
    }
    
    func loadImageFromURL (){
        guard let urlString = urlString else {
                   return
               }
               
               let url = URL(string: urlString)!
               let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: getImageFromResponse(data:response:error:))
               task.resume()
    }
    
    func getImageFromResponse (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?){
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
            print("no data for image found")
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let loadedImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
                return
            }
            self.imageCache.setCache(forKey: self.urlString!, image: loadedImage)
            self.image = loadedImage
        }
    }
}

class CacheImageManager {
  var cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
  
    func getCache (forKey: String) -> UIImage? {
        print("grabbing from cache")
        return cache.object(forKey: NSString(string: forKey ))
    }
    func setCache(forKey: String, image: UIImage) {
        print("saved to cache")
        return cache.setObject(image, forKey: NSString(string : forKey ))
    }
}
extension CacheImageManager{
    private static var imageCache = CacheImageManager()
    static func getImageCache() -> CacheImageManager {
        imageCache
    }
}
```

**Image View**

```
struct UrlImageView: View{
    @ObservedObject var urlImageModel: UrlImageModel
   
    
    init(urlString: String? ){
        urlImageModel = UrlImageModel(urlString: urlString)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: urlImageModel.image ??  ProfilePicture.placeholderProfileImage!)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width:150, height: 150)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .shadow(color: Color("LightWhite"), radius: 9, x: 0, y: 13)
                  
    }     
    
}
```

**Parent View**

```
struct ProfilePicture: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = DashboardLogic()
    static var placeholderProfileImage = UIImage(named: "profileDefaultPicture" )
    var body: some View {
            VStack{
                UrlImageView(urlString: vm.userModel?.profilePictureURL)  
        }     
    }      
}
```

EDIT**
The console is printing
*cache not detected --
cache not detected --
grabbing from cache* - the issue appears that the UrlImageModel is not detecting the cache possibly?
cache located

Comment: You should not use `@ObservedObject` for the _owner_ for an `ObservableObject` -- use `@StateObject` (where you have `DashboardLogic`). May not fix your issue, but it's good practice to solve other issues.

Comment: You also shouldn't be creating an `ObservableObject` in `init` like you are doing in `URLImageView` -- use `@StateObject` there as well

Comment: @jnpdx You helped me on quite a few issues on here, always helpful tips. Thank you, appreciate it!